# Connection closed while receiving data(image through NetworkImage) flutter while retriving data from localhost

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-image

While retrieving the image file from network `http://10.0.2.2:8000` localhost  I got the following error:
`Connection closed while receiving data.`

I have an error when I call data (images only) from the URL.
Note that I am using a local server.
I’m trying to put the image inside `Image.network()`, this is image code.

```dart
Image.network(urllink)
```

The same URL works properly in the localhost browser and postman also.
I am trying to retrieve images in the decoration box widget.
The same url and image work when I paste direct url in the network image function but an error occurred when I tried to fetch the photoname through the apis.
The photoname and APIs I am getting are working fine. There is not any problem with it.

```dart
 child: FutureBuilder<MatrimonyProfileData>(
                  future: futureMData,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      // String matrimonyUrl = '/$matrimonyprofileUrl';
                      String photoName = snapshot.data!.matrimonies.photo;

                      print(photoName);
                      //var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl

                      var url;
                      // urllink = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/matrimony/profile.jpg';

                      **url = (webLink + matrimony + photoName);
                      print(url);
                      String urllink = Url;**
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent.shade100,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: Colors.black, width: 3)),
                                  child: Wrap(
                                    // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    // direction: Axis.vertical,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      
                                Container(
                                  height: 300,
                                  width: 400,
                                  //color: Colors.amber,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(
                                          height: 300,
                                          width: 170,
                                          //color: Colors.amber,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                                image: **NetworkImage(urllink),**

                                                
                                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                                            
                                          )),
                                      // SizedBox(
                                      //   width: 20,
                                      // ),
```

same problem on this link also
`https://askandroidquestions.com/2021/07/12/flutter-exception-connection-closed-while-receiving-data/`

Comment: Share your http request code from which you are retrieving this network url?

Comment: class Network {
    final String _url = siteUrl;
  var token;
  _getToken() async {
    return token;
  }
  getData(apiUrl) async {
     return await http.get(Uri.parse(fullUrl), headers: _setHeaders());
   
  }

  _setHeaders() => {        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
      };

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing `Keep-Alive` header in your http request.

Try adding this to your request headers:

```
  "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
```

Comment: already done but not succeeded

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but it seems to have worked for me.

I have a server running flask and my flutter app calls back to that for data. I also got the same error, but not with NetworkImage specifically, but this should also work for that too.

I also went searching for answers and have added not only the `'Connection' : 'keep-alive'` and `"Keep-Alive": "timeout=20, max=5"` headers, but to no success. So this is what I've done to not solve the issue completely, but it does significantly lower the chances of getting that error.

Basically I have generic api call functions to handle sending data and image data to the server, and I've wrapped the parts of those functions that actually make the http requests in a while loop that uses tracking variables to check if a response was received or not during the allotted number of attempts.

This is basically the idea to follow:

```
// make sure to get your data ready above here, if any
int attempts = 5;
bool gotResponse = false;
String errMsg = "";

while (attempts > 0) {
    attempts = attempts - 1;
    try {
        // this is where you make the http.get or http.post request
        // once you have a response and validate it, then set
        // gotResponse = true
    } catch (err) {
        // set your tracking variables for failure checking here
        gotResponse = false;
        errMsg = err.toString();
    }
}

if (gotResponse == false) {
    throw Exception("$errMsg");
} else {
    throw Exception("Everything's broken");
}
```

It might not be a very elegant solution, but it got the job done for me. And at least you can specify how many times to retry the connection if you have a similar issue to me where the connection sometimes closes multiple times in a row.

Hope this helps.